# How are the objects (access points) in ScanResult List ordered?

Tags: android

I am getting the List of ScanResult object from the getScanResults() call in Android. I want to know how are the objects ordered in the list?

Answer (score 0):

By definition those elements are unordered. And this is what you should act on.
I tried to find out, if there is an order defined somewhere in the android source, but the part of the code is depending on the actual device. 
Even if you can actually figure out an order of the list, you can not guarantee it on any other device.